# Display div after its actual position

Tags: css

I am not sure if this is possible. I have a page setup like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

The sidebar is set to `float:right`. It's fine apart from when I resize the window down (as it's responsive), the sidebar appears *above* the content. It's set to `position:static` and has no float.

Is it possible to make the sidebar appear 'after' the "main" div when in responsive mode - through CSS only? I can't think of a way to do it using pseudo-elements etc.

PS: I cannot move the .sidebar div down below the .main div in the HTML, because then Google decides it doesn't want to show my author avatar as it's "not relevant" i.e. too far down so ignores it.

Comment: What do you mean with after the main div? this could be looked at in several ways, give us a link to a page or an example that describes the effect you are looking to achieve if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Google showing your avatar is not the result of how far down it is. Google looks for this bit of html:

```
rel=author
```

See this article: http://searchengineland.com/googleplus-slowly-invading-googles-main-search-results-102416

Once you do that you can switch the order of your html to have "main" first, and then float "main" and "sidebar" left at the appropriate breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not true. There is a message within Webmaster Tools that says 'Google has decided this information isn't relevant'. Once you move it up the page, that message disappears, and the rich snippets work.